# Laravel several models on the same table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need a database with Questions and Answers. I want to to put those questions and answers on the same database table named Post. There will be a field post_type, which tell me the post is a question or an answer.

How can I achieve this in Laravel models?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is called single table inheritance. You can find a way of implementing this here : http://www.colorfultyping.com/single-table-inheritance-in-laravel-4/

Basically, following this method, you will have a field called `object_class` in your `posts` table, which is what you called `post_type`, containing the class name of the model to instanciate when selecting a post.

The good thing with this method is that whatever method you used to retrieve a model instance (first, where, find...), the right class will be instantiated.

For example :

```
// this will return an Answer instance (if the class_name is Answer)
$post = Post::find(1); 

// which will be the same as
$answer = Answer::find(1);

// and this will return nothing
$question = Question::find(1);
```

Comment: Good to know that it worked out. If it solved your problem don't forget to mark the answer as validated.

Comment: I test and see that your solution works. Besides, it is a fact that Question::find(1) will never return an Answer instance. :), Thanks again, alxscms

Comment: Yes, my bad. This problem happened to me because I had more than one level of hierarchy (SportCar -> SportVehicle -> Vehicle). I'll edit my answer, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Um simply map a model to that table using Eloquent like you would with any other Model > Table mapping.

Then you can simply call:

```
// Find the post
$post = Post::find(1);

// Check if post is question, assuming post_type is boolean/tiny int type
if($post->post_type)
{
  // Post is question if post_type is true
} else {
  // Post is an anwser
}
```

When you are inserting/adding new post make sure to set post_type to weather it's a question or answer.

This is all well and will work but it's bad programming practice mate. You really should separate this into 3 tables: `Post, Question, Answer` and have relations between the three.

Comment: Hello Kellax. Actually, I can separate into 3 tables for easier programming but I think it will cause me for more difficulty when dealing with search functions. That's reason.